# Find 2 point with same distance from A

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a math problem. I have location (x,y) of point A, B, and a number (x). I want to calculate the location of point C, D. CD is perpendicular with AB and AC = AD = x.

This is the picture describe my problem:

[image: my problem]

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know vectors ?

Comment: Yes, I know vector, you mean perpendicular vector?

Comment: Ok well then I added an answer with a vector method ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you know vectors:

What you have is:

- The coordinates of $A$ and $B$ : $(x_A,y_A)$ and $(x_B,y_B)$
- A value $x$ such that: $\|\vec{AC}\|=\|\vec{AD}\|=x$
- The fact that $\vec{AC}\cdot\vec{AB}=0$ and $\vec{AD}\cdot\vec{AB}=0$ (since they are orthogonal)

Also, you can see that: $\vec{AD}=-\vec{AC}$. So what you have to do is only find $\vec{AC}$ and you'll have $\vec{AD}$.

Now, let's rewrite your dot product equation:

$$\left(\vec{AC}\cdot\vec{AB}=0\right)\Rightarrow\left(\vec{AC}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{cc}x_B-x_A\\y_B-y_A\end{array}\right)=0\right)$$

**Note:** An easy way to find an orthogonal 2D vector is by switching the coordinates and taking the opposite of one of them. An example might be clearer:

Say you want to find an orthogonal vector to $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a\\b\end{array}\right)$:

1. Switch the coordinates: $\left(\begin{array}{cc}b\\a\end{array}\right)$
2. Take the opposite of one of them (the $b$ for instance): $\left(\begin{array}{cc}-b\\a\end{array}\right)$

And here you go, you have found an orthogonal vector to $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a\\b\end{array}\right)$.

Alright, now let's go back to our problem. Which was to find a vector $\vec{X}$ orthogonal to $\left(\begin{array}{cc}x_B-x_A\\y_B-y_A\end{array}\right)$. With the method we just used, we can find that:

$$\vec{X}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-(y_B-y_A)\\x_B-x_A\end{array}\right)$$

$\vec{AC}$ is also orthogonal to $\vec{AB}$ so $\vec{AC}$ is colinear to $\vec{X}$ and so:

$$\vec{AC}=\lambda\vec{X}$$

However, we also need $\|\vec{AC}\|=x$. For the moment $\|\vec{X}\|=\left\|\left(\begin{array}{cc}-(y_B-y_A)\\x_B-x_A\end{array}\right)\right\|=\|\vec{AB}\|=AB$

This means that $\left\|\left(\dfrac{x}{AB}\right)\vec{X}\right\|=\dfrac{x}{AB}\left\|\vec{X}\right\|=x$

So here you go:

$$\vec{AC}=\dfrac{x}{AB}\vec{X}=\dfrac{x}{AB}\left(\begin{array}{cc}-(y_B-y_A)\\x_B-x_A\end{array}\right)$$